# How do I resolve more than one promise while loading a state in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am loading a /home state, and I want to grab all of my users from the database so I can manipulate the home controller and view based on what user is logged in.  Currently I am grabbing all of the 'posts' that are in the database in my :resolve section of the state configuration.  However, I cannot figure out how to implement more than one promise at a time.

This is my state code for /home

```
  $stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
      return posts.getAll();
      // I want to resolve more than one promise here.  
    }]
  }
})
```

Basically I just want to be able to run a users.getAll() during the resolve of the /home state.  I cannot figure out the syntax to do this.

Comment: Why not return an object `return {posts: posts.getAll, foos: foos.getAll}` ? otherwise you'd have to have multiple resolve elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a second resolve to your state configuration:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
      return posts.getAll();
      // I want to resolve more than one promise here.  
    }],
    userPromise: ['users', function(users){
      return users.getAll();
    }]
  }
})
```

or, as an alternative use  $q.all([userPromise, postsPromise]): this gives you a promise that is resolved as soon as all the promises in the array are resolved and as value you will get an array with the results of each promise in the array.